# change color for only one Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#-4.0

I know, this is a beginner question, but I want to change the background colour only for this sentence but it colours all the text.

```
Console.WriteLine("healing spell:", Console. BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green);
```

This is what I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, did you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Cyan;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.